# Akka-Java interprocess communication

Tags: java, scala, tomcat, akka, multi-tier

I have a monolithic Java application (frontend/services) running in Tomcat. I'm trying to come up with a design that will allow me to slowly migrate all the parts of the application as individual tiers to (one or more) Akka actor system(s). As a first redesign, I want to keep the client facing frontend in Tomcat and rewrite some of the middle tier logic in Akka.

I have a couple questions about how to go with this redesign:

- What's the most efficient way for the frontend to communicate with Akka? I was considering REST but I was wondering if there was anything faster;
- How hard is it to reuse the existing JPA/hybernate entity model from within Akka? I am looking for documentation/gotchas.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akka supports [remoting](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/java/remoting.html), which is actors talking to actors on other systems.   You can have actors in your Tomcat app communicate with actors in the services running elsewhere.

Since JPA/Hibernate/JDBC is blocking you should [take special care](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/general/actor-systems.html#Blocking_Needs_Careful_Management) on how you use it in your actor-based apps.

Comment: This is very interesting. I read the section about remoting and it looks to me like I can just add code to lookup my remote actor from my Tomcat app, am I right? And that'll use the remoting protocol I specify?

Comment: Right- though I would recommend using the remote transport as shown in the "Preparing your ActorSystem for Remoting" section.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to split your application and need a high IPC/Network link, consider a brokerless messaging lib instead of akka, e.g. https://code.google.com/p/fast-cast/

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to slowly migrate all the services to Akka, but I will leave the frontend unchanged for now.

Comment: Ok, then you might want to add this to your post :-)

Comment: I thought the sentence "I'm trying to come up with a design that allows me to move some of the middle tier services to an Akka actor system to start porting the whole application" was pretty clear...